# Button not working in android app?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm building an app which has 3 functions a converter, a calculator and a notes section. When I click on the converter button on the home page it brings me to the converter activity / page. But when I click on the calculator button on the home page it won't open. Here is the code below. Any reason as to why? Thanks in advance.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.qub.buildersbuddy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonConverter; 
    Button buttonCalculator;
    Button buttonNotePad;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button ConvertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butonConverter);
        ConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CentInch.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    public void setupConverterButton(){
        buttonConverter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butonConverter);
        // Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butonConverter);

}

    public void CentToInch(){
        buttonConverter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //opening the
                try{
                    Class centClass = Class
                            .forName("com.qub.buildersbuddy.CentInch");
                    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,centClass);
            startActivity(myintent);
                }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
    });

}

protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button CalcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);
    CalcBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculator.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

public void setupCalculatorButton(){
    buttonCalculator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalc);
    // Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butonConverter);

}

public void Calculator(){
    buttonCalculator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //opening the
            try{
                Class calcClass = Class
                        .forName("com.qub.buildersbuddy.Calculator");
                Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,calcClass);
        startActivity(myintent);
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
});

}
}
```

**activity_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CentInch" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butonConverter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="Converter" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCalc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/butonConverter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Calculator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonCalc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="Notes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "Won't open" as in nothing at all happens? In that case something is probably misspelled somewhere

Comment: there are fundamental errors in your. why do you have onCreate1 method? and because of that some of your methods are ever called. Please reorganize your code and methods, you only need one onCreate method and call any other methods you want from within. as you have more than two buttons i would also advice to implements onClickListener which will be easier and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the exact code you're using?  Your #onCreate1 method will never get called.  #onCreate gets called because it overrides a method from the class you extended (Activity), and something in Activity calls the method when the activity first starts.  Move your calculator button logic into the first #onCreate method.